# error 500 on xampp using htacces (Password)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, error-handling, server

Hi I am getting error 500 on Apache webserver using xampp. The error wasnt there until i used a .htaccess, .htpasswd file. I searched and i couldnt find a syntax error. I have only 1 image and the index file I want to protect. Here are the syntaxes:
.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Prosím přihlašte se.";
AuthUserFile C:\xampp\htdocs\Zprávy 1.E\.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

.htpasswd

```
 zak:$apr1$t8hZiqXE$0qdoQ/876dOqysUmww2NM/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error on your .htaccess file, you should quote the file path because it has space between.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Prosím přihlašte se.";
AuthUserFile "C:\xampp\htdocs\Zprávy 1.E\.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```